# Greatest Common Denominator and linear combination

Tags: abstract-algebra, elementary-number-theory

I know the gcd of 616 and 427 is 7, but I know need to do a linear combination of it. So there exists $x, y$ such that $$7=616x+427y$$ How do I solve for x and y?

Comment: Do you know Euclid's algorithm?

Comment: yea I did that for to get 7, but Im just having trouble doing it in reverse

Comment: The extended gcd, is this what you want? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm

Comment: Sorry, my browser got the wrong url. I have corrected that.

Comment: yes I want that. I keep trying to do it this way. http://www.jstor.org/stable/3618530. at the bottom but I just cant work it out

Comment: $616=427+189, 427=2\cdot189+49,189=3\cdot49+42,49=42+7,42=6\cdot7$. Now reverse. $7=49-42=-189+4\cdot49=4\cdot427-9\cdot189=13\cdot427-9\cdot616$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this:

$$616=1\cdot427+189$$

$$427=2\cdot189+49$$

$$189=3\cdot 49+42$$

$$49=1\cdot42+7$$

Now we reverse the process

$$7=49-42=49-(189-3\cdot49)=4\cdot49-189$$

where we expanded $42$ using the third line of the original calculation. Expanding $49$ using the second line and then $189$ using the first line we get first: $$=4\cdot(427-2\cdot189)-189=4\cdot427-9\cdot189$$ then $$=4\cdot 477-9\cdot(616-427)=13\cdot427-9\cdot616$$

and this is the expression you are looking for.

---

Note: this is very similar to an answer math love posted and then deleted (I'm not sure why). My presentation is intended to emphasise the pattern and mechanical nature of the process, when done like this, rather than to emphasise efficiency or insight.

Answer (score 2):

Use the euclidean algorithm to reach seven, then backtrack substituting until you reach the first equation. That is:

$$
616=1*427+189
$$
$$
427=2*189+49
$$
$$
189=3*49+42
$$
$$
49=1*42+7
$$

Now we want to solve for seven in terms of the above equations. For ease of notation let $616=x$ and $427=y$. Then the first equation tells us that

$$
x=y+189
$$
so $x-y=189$. Now substituting this into the second equation we have:

$$
y=2(x-y)+49
$$
and so $3y-2x=49$. Next we substitute what we know into the next equation and find:
$$
(x-y)=3*(3y-2x)+42
$$
so
$$
7x-10y=42
$$
Then the last equation tells us
$$
3y-2x=7x-10y+7
$$
So we have

$13y-9x=7$

and indeed this is so as $13*427+(-9)*616=7$.